# Curl failed: OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to fcm.googleapis.com:443 in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I integrated Fire-base Notification CRUL Code with Codeigniter. sometimes I am getting an error but not all the times.

I have integrated below code to the controller

Controller Code

```
$newDate=Date('m-d-Y H:i:s');

$test_str=$user->us_name. ' Clocked at '.$newDate;
$res = array();

$res['data']['title'] = $user->us_name.' - Clocked In';
$res['data']['is_background'] = "TRUE";
$res['data']['message'] = $test_str;
$res['data']['image'] = 'http://api.androidhive.info/images/minion.jpg';
$res['data']['payload'] = 'individual';
$res['data']['timestamp'] = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
$res['data']['act_tab'] = 0;


$cur_id1=$this->db->query("Select token from devices")->result();

foreach($cur_id1 as $cur_id) {

    $fields = array('to' => $cur_id->token,'data' => $res);
    $this->notif_model->sendPushNotification($fields);
}
```

Model Code

```
function sendPushNotification($fields) {


        // Set POST variables
        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=MyServerKey',
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
    }
```

While running this sometimes I am getting the error

> Curl failed: OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to fcm.googleapis.com:443

Comment: Try after adding this line `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);` works for me

Comment: ok. i will try...

Comment: i  tried this but still i am getting error...

Comment: @GopalBhuva If there's something wrong with your SSL connection, you've got to fix that instead of ignoring these errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);`

Comment: Application is hosted on go-daddy server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46403217/openssl-ssl-connect-ssl-error-syscall-in-connection-to-api-amazonalexa-com443?rq=1

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48559355/why-i-am-getting-openssl-ssl-connect-ssl-error-syscall-in-connection-error-on

Looks like godaddy hosting has problems. You need to contact with support and describe your problem to them. maybe outdated curl or openssl.

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendPushNotification($fields) {


        // Set POST variables
        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=MyServerKey',
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);

        // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
    }
```